# Do XML namespaces need to be declared in the root element to be matchable by an XPath query?

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I can't figure out whether XPath itself is to blame or whether it's the particular XPath implementations that make this so difficult. The SO question – [How to change an an XML element in a namespace with MSDeploy Parameters.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830296/how-to-change-an-an-xml-element-in-a-namespace-with-msdeploy-parameters-xml-file) – was my inspiration.

## What Doesn't Work

Here's the basic example that doesn't work.

XML:

```
<spring>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
        <object id="CultureResolver" type="Spring.Globalization.Resolvers.SessionCultureResolver, Spring.Web">
             <!--configure for server--> 
            <property name="DefaultCulture" value="en" />
        </object>
    </objects>
</spring>
```

XPath:

```
//spring/objects/object[@id='CultureResolver']/@type
```

The XPath query returns nothing instead of:

```
Spring.Globalization.Resolvers.SessionCultureResolver, Spring.Web
```

## What I Expect to Work

I would, perhaps naively, expect the following to work.

Modified XML:

```
<spring>
    <spring:objects xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.net">
        <spring:object id="CultureResolver" type="Spring.Globalization.Resolvers.SessionCultureResolver, Spring.Web">
             <!--configure for server--> 
            <spring:property name="DefaultCulture" value="en" />
        </spring:object>
    </spring:objects>
</spring>
```

Modified XPath query:

```
//spring/spring:objects/spring:object[@id='CultureResolver']/@type
```

This query raises an error in [the online tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) I used:

```
ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: org.apache.xpath.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: spring
```

## What Does Work

Modified XML:

```
<spring xmlns="" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.net">
    <spring:objects>
        <spring:object id="CultureResolver" type="Spring.Globalization.Resolvers.SessionCultureResolver, Spring.Web">
             <!--configure for server--> 
            <spring:property name="DefaultCulture" value="en" />
        </spring:object>
    </spring:objects>
</spring>
```

Modified XPath query (same as under *What I Expect to Work*):

```
//spring/spring:objects/spring:object[@id='CultureResolver']/@type
```

To add to the confusion somewhat, I discovered that the following XPath query works for the original example XML (in the online tester XPath engine):

```
//spring/*[local-name() = 'objects' and namespace-uri() = 'http://www.springframework.net']/*[@id='CultureResolver' and local-name() = 'object' and namespace-uri() = 'http://www.springframework.net']/@type
```

## Why?

Is this confusing because of the interplay between namespaces and prefixes? It seems like declaring a namespace without a prefix not only includes the relevant element in that namespace but also includes all of its children too, hence describing it as a "default namespace" (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12262273/173497) to a related question). Whereas declaring a namespace with a prefix doesn't even include the relevant element in that namespace!

Is there some reason why namespaces *need* to be included in the root element of the XML document, independent of particular XPath implementations?

## My XPath Engines

The problem I was trying to solve involved whatever XPath engine that Microsoft Web Deploy (MSDeploy) uses.

I was also using [this online XPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).

Comment: You have declare the namespace prefix before you can use it validly is all it is. Having a schema would tidy things up a bit, you could shove the namespace declarations in there then, use spring:spring and all the 'spring' stuff would be in the same namespace.

Comment: The important question is: What environment / programming language do you use Xpath in? Then, we can answer your questions.

Comment: @MathiasMüller you seemed to do an excellent job answering my question even before I added info about my environment and XPath engine to my question!

Comment: Kenny, even though your question is marked as answered, could you clarify a couple of things to make this question more helpful to others: 1) When you say something "worked" vs. "didn't work," do you mean it selected a `type` attribute vs. selected nothing? 2) Does the middle section, titled 'What I Expect to Work', actually work (as defined in question 1) or not?

Comment: Elaborating on question 1: did those that "didn't work" give an error message? If so, what did it say?

Comment: @LarsH Yes, the two queries that don't work return nothing versus the value of the `type` attribute; I edited the question to include that info. Neither query results in an error or exception, in any of the XPath engines I used (MSBuild and the online tester).

Comment: Interesting: Using the online XPath tester that you linked to, in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, the "What I Expect to Work" configuration throws an exception: `ERROR - Failed to evaluate XPath expression: org.apache.xpath.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: spring`. Since you didn't get an error, were you using IE?

Comment: @LarsH Interesting indeed – seems my memory was less than perfect. I got the same result as you just now. I updated the question. Thanks for the input.

Comment: "The namespace prefix, unless it is xml or xmlns, must have been declared in a namespace declaration attribute in either the start-tag of the element where the prefix is used or in an an ancestor element"  So that oughta be legal to declare it in the same element you use it. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An interesting and well-asked question! As far as I can see, the difficulty lies with the way your XPath engine handles namespace declarations found in the input document.

**The short answer**

No, this behaviour has nothing to do with XPath in general or with the XPath specification. It is due to individual implementations.

---

**What the specifications say**

As far as the XML and XPath specifications are concerned, namespaces can be declared on any element, and there is nothing special about the outermost (or "root") element. Namespace declarations on the root element are just like any other declaration.

Of course there are still rules. For instance, a prefix must be associated with a namespace URI on the element in whose QName it is used, or on an ancestor of that element (or of that attribute). So, the following is not well-formed XML:

```
<prefix:root>
    <child xmlns:prefix="www.example.com"/>
</prefix:root>
```

And the second important rule: A *default namespace* can only apply to the element on which it is declared and all descendant elements. In the following document, the `root` element is in no namespace at all:

```
<root>
   <child xmlns="www.example.com">
      <grandchild/>
   </child>
</root>
```

The specifications I am talking about are the [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), [XML Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) and [Xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) specifications.

**What happens in your implementation of XPath**

Now, if an XPath expression is evaluated against an XML document, all namespace declarations present in this input document must also explicitly be made available (declared, or "registered") to the XPath engine.

Some implementations of XPath simplify this by simply **redeclaring all namespace declarations that are in scope for an element or attribute** of an XML document that serves as input for an Xpath engine (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816050/simplexml-and-xpath-read-sibling/27816518?noredirect=1#comment44068542_27816518)).

In your case, it seems only declarations made on the outermost element are considered. That's why your last XML document:

```
<spring xmlns="" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.net">
    <spring:objects>
        <spring:object id="CultureResolver" type="Spring.Globalization.Resolvers.SessionCultureResolver, Spring.Web">
             <!--configure for server--> 
            <spring:property name="DefaultCulture" value="en" />
        </spring:object>
    </spring:objects>
</spring>
```

works - because the namespace declaration is made on the root element and you execute the XPath expression from the root element. You could omit the undeclaration of a default namespace though, because it doesn't have any effect.

---

Finally, to answer your last question:

> Is there some reason why namespaces need to be included in the root element of the XML document, independent of particular XPath implementations?

No, there is no reason namespace declarations should be on the root element, except

- that they are somewhat easier to find when declared on the root element, in my opinion (highly subjective)
- if you'd like to declare a default namespace for the whole document. Declaring it on the root element is the only way to have it also apply to the root element
- if the root element itself has a qualified name, i.e. is *prefixed*. Then, you must declare this prefix and namespace URI on the root element.

If your implementation of XPath automatically redeclares namespace declarations that are in scope, you can of course take advantage of it, but it will also be confusing sometimes, as you have noticed.

Comment: That code is actually well-formed (namespaces don't break wellformedness), it just won't regard "prefix" as a namespace prefix. "prefix:root" will just be a name containing a colon.

Comment: @Dabbler No, that's not true. Any application that can check the well-formedness of XML will complain about such a document. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I did try it, using XMLSpy. Did you? ;-)

Comment: @Dabbler Then let me rephrase my statement: Yes, [XML parsers theoretically must accept names with colons](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn), but in practice names with colons are identified as [qualified names](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-qualnames). No, I don't have XMLSpy, I checked with Oxygen.

Comment: Not "theoretically". The code is well-formed, and XML processors are required to treat it as well-formed. Anyway, let's not argue about it ,-)

Comment: @Dabbler you did a pretty good job of arguing in a way that exposed the relevant info – that XPath engine implementations diverge from the XPath spec. That's good to know! To add to the 'argument', the online tester to which I linked also seems to treat names with colons as qualified names and complains if what it's interpreting as a prefix doesn't match a namespace declaration. I suspect the XPath engine that Web Deploy uses might be the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, the namespace definition for the document and XPath are separate. Some implementations automatically register the space definitions of the current context by default. I consider this a bug, because it makes the XPath ambiguous.

Let's start with a simple example:

```
<foo:element xmlns:foo="urn:foo"/>
```

That defines an alias/prefix `foo` for the namespace `urn:foo`. The XML parser resolves that and recognizes that the node `element` belongs to the namespace `urn:foo`. For debugging reason the node name could be written as `{urn:foo}element`.

If you change the prefix, or even remove it this is always resolved the same way. Consider the following examples:

```
<foo:element xmlns:foo="urn:foo"/>
<bar:element xmlns:bar="urn:foo"/>
<element xmlns="urn:foo"/>
```

The prefix/alias is only valid for the node and its descendants. Any descendant can have its own definition that possibly can overwrite the one of its ancestor.

For XPath you define you own aliases. You write a namespace resolver or register them on the XPath engine. That really depends on the implementation.

Here is a small PHP example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<foo:element xmlns:foo="urn:foo"/>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('alias', 'urn:foo');

var_dump($xpath->evaluate('name(/alias:element)'));
```

Output:

```
string(11) "foo:element"
```

You can see that the namespace definitions for the XPath are separate and independent from the prefixes defined in the XML document.

In Javascript XPath is used with the `Document.evaluate()`. The third argument is the namespace resolver.

```
var resolver = {
  namespaces : {
   'alias' : 'urn:foo'
  },
  lookupNamespaceURI : function(prefix) {
    if (prefix == '') {
      return null;
    }
    return this.namespaces[prefix] || null;
  }
};

console.log(
    document.evaluate(
       'name(/alias:element)'
    ),
    document,
    resolver,
    XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
    null
  ).stringValue
);
```

Back to you question. You have to find out how you register/define the aliases/prefixes for you namespaces. After that you can use them in you XPath expressions. If you define the alias `spring` for the namespace `http://www.springframework.net"` the following XPath expression should work:

`//spring/spring:objects/spring:object[@id='CultureResolver']/@type`

Comment: +1 for "I consider this a bug, because it makes the XPath ambiguous." This kind of behavior is convenient for certain simple cases, but results in effects that are very confusing in the general case... especially when the behavior isn't documented (which it might be for these XPath engines... I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

In "What doesn't Work", the problem is that `<object>` and its descendants are in the `http://www.springframework.net` namespace, but the XPath expression is asking for an `<object>` that is in no namespace.

It's not immediately apparent why "What I Expect to Work" shouldn't work, because `<objects>` and `<object>` are both explicitly in the `http://www.springframework.net` namespace, and the XPath expression qualifies the element names correctly (assuming that whatever code resolves the `spring` prefix has access to the namespace bindings).

In "What Does Work", again, `<objects>` and `<object>` are both explicitly in the `http://www.springframework.net` namespace, and the XPath expression qualifies the element names correctly.

The difference to "What I Expect to Work" is that the default namespace, which applies to `<spring>`, is explicitly bound to no namespace; so I can only guess that with "What I Expect to Work", the default namespace (which applies to  `<spring>`) is bound to some namespace you are not aware of. I suggest you check whether `//spring` works - I guess that will already reveal a problem.

Comment: There _are_ no namespace bindings, that's the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: Missing namespace bindings don't explain the difference between "What I Expect to Work" and "What Does Work", though.

Comment: Of course, the Xpath engine is only handed namespace declarations found on the root element of the document.