# Same xpath works on command line but not in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm a beginning user of xslt and xpath.  Using an xpath on a command line (Ubuntu 14.04) with a xml file works, but the very same xpath in an xslt file returns nothing.  I'm working with Juniper Junos xml files.  Any suggestions?
Thanks,
George

The xml file begins with:

```
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.3R8/junos">
  <interface-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.3R8/junos-interface" junos:style="normal">
    <physical-interface>
      <name>fe-0/1/0</name>
      <logical-interface>
        <name>fe-0/1/0.0</name>
          ...
```

The command line that works in Ubuntu 14.04 is:
`xpath -e "/rpc-reply/interface-information/physical-interface/logical-interface/name" interfaces.xml`

The xslt file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Interfaces</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/rpc-reply/interface-information/physical-interface/logical-interface">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's clear that your XPath is failing in XSLT because you've not taken namespaces into account.  It's not clear what utility you're running under Ubuntu that is ignoring namespaces or has registered them somehow perhaps without you realizing it.  Are you sure the command is called "xpath" and it's not  xmllint or xmlstarlet?

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, there is a Unix command `xpath`, and you're right, it simply [redeclares namespace declarations found on the outermost element of the input document](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28119460/1987598).

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Thank you.  How perniciously convenient that behavior is!

Comment: @kjhughes I have to correct myself, more precisely, all non-default namespace declarations that are in scope for an element or attribute are redeclared.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Cool.  Either way, though, does this explain how OP's command line could have worked given that it has no namespace prefixes in it, even if the tool auto-declared them?  My "pernicious" comment was meant to refer more to auto-associating (or outrightly ignoring) the namespaces more so than auto-declaring prefixes for them.

Comment: @kjhughes Yes, because default namespaces are still ignored. And the command really works with my bash shell, and using a well-formed version of the small snippet the OP has shown.

Comment: @MathiasMüller: Got it.  Ignoring default namespaces specifically is pernicious.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is quite simple. You are not using namespaces in your XPaths. Apparently your command line utility <s>doesn't care, or evaluates XPaths based on the elements' QNames</s> ignores default namespaces and does some other non-standard handling of namespaces as well.

**The solution:**

Declare prefixes at the top of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:nbase="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0"
  xmlns:junosi="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.3R8/junos-interface"
>
```

use those prefixes in your XPaths:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/nbase:rpc-reply/junosi:interface-information
                        /junosi:physical-interface/junosi:logical-interface">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="junosi:name"/></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Two valid hypotheses, but in fact, the `xpath` command redeclares namespaces declarations that are in scope for every element and attribute. If no declaration is in scope, a prefixed element cannot be found. Default namespaces are ignored.

Comment: @MathiasMüller So I grasped the part about my guesses being incorrect, but not sure I got the rest 100%. Are you saying that this tool could treat the two `my`s in `/my:root/my:child` as two different namespaces (if `child` redeclared `my` with a new URI)? And by _"If no declaration is in scope, a prefixed element cannot be found."_ you mean that an XPath with prefixes would come back empty-handed? Surely within an XML document, a prefixed element in the absence of any in-scope namespace declarations would constitute invalid XML.

Comment: To be sure, I just tried everything once again (not using a true [xmlsh shell](http://www.xmlsh.org/CommandXpath), but the xpath command from my Mac OS X shell). I'm not sure what you mean by "treating prefixes as different namespaces", but in a document where there is only `my:root` and `my:child` and the namespace is redeclared on the child element with a different URI, yes,  `/my:root/my:child` retrieves the node.

Comment: If the same expression is evaluated against a document without prefixed elements, no nodes are found. And finally, no, the tool does not complain if a prefix is used out of scope. Theoretically, ["XML processors must accept the colon as a name character"](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn) if I understood that bit of the specification correctly.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Because you said the tool "redeclares namespaces", I was simply wondering if, given `<my:parent xmlns:my="a"><my:child xmlns:my="b" /></my:parent>` the tool would successfully select an element `/my:parent/my:child`, effectively treating `my` as `{a}` in the first step and `{b}` in the second step. It sounds like the answer to that question is "yes".

Comment: Yes, I understood what you were saying. I tried again now, with exactly your suggestion: `$ xpath input.xml "/my:parent/my:child"
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
<my:child xmlns:my="b" />`

Comment: @MathiasMüller And I imagine that in a document such as `<my:parent xmlns:my="a"><my:child xmlns:my="b" /><my:child xmlns:my="c" /></my:parent>`, the `my` in the second step of that XPath would be matching two different namespace URIs at the same time. I realize my language is probably imprecise. I'm just trying to grok the extent to which this tool flies in the face of what one familiar with namespaces in XPath would typically expect.

Comment: `$ xpath input.xml "/my:parent/my:child"
Found 2 nodes:
-- NODE --
<my:child xmlns:my="b" />-- NODE --
<my:child xmlns:my="c" />` - and yes, that's pretty non-standard. I would be lying if I said I wasn't surprised.