# Transform XML to declare all namespaces on root element

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sax, stax

Is there a simple Java <del>method</del> way of "moving" all XML namespace declarations of an XML document to the root element? Due to a bug in parser implementation of an unnamed huge company, I need to programmatically rewrite our well formed and valid RPC requests in a way that the root element declares all used namespaces.

Not OK:

```xml
<document-element xmlns="uri:ns1">
    <foo>
        <bar xmlns="uri:ns2" xmlns:ns3="uri:ns3">
            <ns3:foobar/>
            <ns1:sigh xmlns:ns1="uri:ns1"/>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</document-element>
```

OK:

```xml
<document-element xmlns="uri:ns1" xmlns:ns1="uri:ns1" xmlns:ns2="uri:ns2" xmlns:ns3="uri:ns3">
    <foo>
        <ns2:bar>
            <ns3:foobar/>
            <ns1:sigh/>
        </ns2:bar>
    </foo>
</document-element>
```

Generic names for <del>missing</del> prefixes are acceptable. Default namespace may stay or be replaced/added as long as it is defined on the root element. I don't really mind which specific XML technology is used to achieve this (I would prefer to avoid DOM though).

To clarify, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119460/878469) refers to what I'd like to achieve as *redeclaring namespace declarations* within root element scope (entire document) on the root element. Essentially the related question is asking why oh why would anyone implement what I now need to work around.

Comment: Probably no "simple" java function because in theory there could be the same prefix with different namespace URIs inside different subtrees of the document. Why would you keep namespaces at all? You could use an identity xslt transform that creates `<xsl:element name="local-name()">'... at all places and have a document that doesn't have any namespaces, so by definition all of them are declared ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, getting rid of namespaces altogether is not an option, as that would be non standards compliant. I will leave that in the domain of the unnamed huge company.

Comment: The "method" term I used is meant as in "scientific method", not as a function declaration.

Comment: That's good, a Java method as scientific... You could still use the xslt identity transform and add simply one and the same namespace to all elements including the root, again giving "all" namespaces declared at root level.

Comment: There are some entries in the XSLT FAQ, for instance http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5536.html#d7042e2545 might help, but it is not complete as it does not handle various default namespace declarations at different levels. Generating new prefixes for those nested default namespace declarations and using them when creating result element "copies" seems to be the issue missing and is the most challenging part I think.

Comment: There will be non-trivial coding effort no matter what xml technologies you use... will submit some code soon

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a two-pass StAX reader/writer, which is simple enough.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;

public class NamespacesToRoot {

    private static final String GENERATED_PREFIX = "pfx";

    private final XMLInputFactory inputFact;
    private final XMLOutputFactory outputFact;
    private final XMLEventFactory eventFactory;

    private NamespacesToRoot() {
        inputFact = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        outputFact = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
    }

    public String transform(String xmlString) throws XMLStreamException {
        Map<String, String> pfxToNs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        XMLEventReader reader = null;

        // first pass - analyze
        try {
            if (xmlString == null || xmlString.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("xmlString is null or empty");
            }
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
            XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFact.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
            reader = inputFact.createXMLEventReader(streamReader);

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();                
                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    buildNamespaces(event, pfxToNs);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(pfxToNs);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            }
        }

        // reverse mapping, also gets rid of duplicates
        Map<String, String> nsToPfx = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pfxToNs.entrySet()) {
            nsToPfx.put(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
        List<Namespace> namespaces = new ArrayList<Namespace>(nsToPfx.size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : nsToPfx.entrySet()) {
            namespaces.add(eventFactory.createNamespace(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey()));
        }

        // second pass - rewrite
        XMLEventWriter writer = null;
        try {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            writer = outputFact.createXMLEventWriter(stringWriter);

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
            XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFact.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
            reader = inputFact.createXMLEventReader(streamReader);

            boolean rootElement = true;
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();                
                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    StartElement origStartElement = event.asStartElement();
                    String prefix = nsToPfx.get(origStartElement.getName().getNamespaceURI());
                    String namespace = origStartElement.getName().getNamespaceURI();
                    String localName = origStartElement.getName().getLocalPart();
                    Iterator attributes = origStartElement.getAttributes();
                    Iterator namespaces_;
                    if (rootElement) {
                        namespaces_ = namespaces.iterator();                        
                        rootElement = false;
                    } else {
                        namespaces_ = null;
                    }
                    writer.add(eventFactory.createStartElement(
                            prefix, namespace, localName, attributes, namespaces_));
                } else {
                    writer.add(event);
                }                
            }

            writer.flush();

            return stringWriter.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            }
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildNamespaces(XMLEvent event, Map<String, String> pfxToNs) {
        System.out.println("el: " + event);
        StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
        Iterator nsIternator = startElement.getNamespaces();
        while (nsIternator.hasNext()) {
            Namespace nsAttr = (Namespace) nsIternator.next();
            if (nsAttr.isDefaultNamespaceDeclaration()) {
                System.out.println("need to generate a prefix for " + nsAttr.getNamespaceURI());
                generatePrefix(nsAttr.getNamespaceURI(), pfxToNs);
            } else {
                System.out.println("add prefix binding for " + nsAttr.getPrefix() + " --> " + nsAttr.getNamespaceURI());
                addPrefix(nsAttr.getPrefix(), nsAttr.getNamespaceURI(), pfxToNs);
            }
        }
    }

    private void generatePrefix(String namespace, Map<String, String> pfxToNs) {
        int i = 1;
        String prefix = GENERATED_PREFIX + i;
        while (pfxToNs.keySet().contains(prefix)) {
            i++;
            prefix = GENERATED_PREFIX + i;
        }
        pfxToNs.put(prefix, namespace);
    }

    private void addPrefix(String prefix, String namespace, Map<String, String> pfxToNs) {
        String existingNs = pfxToNs.get(prefix);
        if (existingNs != null) {
            if (existingNs.equals(namespace)) {
                // nothing to do
            } else {
                // prefix clash, need to rename this prefix or reuse an existing
                // one
                if (pfxToNs.values().contains(namespace)) {
                    // reuse matching prefix
                } else {
                    // rename
                    generatePrefix(namespace, pfxToNs);
                }                
            }
        } else {
            // need to add this prefix
            pfxToNs.put(prefix, namespace);
        }        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException {
        String xmlString = "" +
"<document-element xmlns=\"uri:ns1\" attr=\"1\">\n" +
"    <foo>\n" +
"        <bar xmlns=\"uri:ns2\" xmlns:ns3=\"uri:ns3\">\n" +
"            <ns3:foobar ns3:attr1=\"meh\" />\n" +
"            <ns1:sigh xmlns:ns1=\"uri:ns1\"/>\n" +
"        </bar>\n" +
"    </foo>\n" +
"</document-element>";
        System.out.println(xmlString);
        NamespacesToRoot transformer = new NamespacesToRoot();
        System.out.println(transformer.transform(xmlString));
    }
}
```

Note that this is just fast example code which could use some tweaks, but is also a good start for anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: Still looking for better alternatives.

Comment: what if there are multiple xmlns:ns1 declaration in the same document do you have to worry about it (in which the XML is definitely borken when you move all declaration in the root element

Comment: @vtd-xml-author, if multiple namespaces are bound to the same prefix, it is first come first serve. It doesn't matter if generic prefixes are used instead of originals.

Comment: but that would alter the prefix and URL binding... sounds troubling to say the least

Comment: @vtd-xml-author, if XML document is semantically equivalent, it doesn't matter. This is a workaround for a bug in someone else's implementation, after all.

Comment: my code has a bug I need to fix tomorrow... sory bout that

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple app does the namespace re-declaration... based on XPath and VTD-XML.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;

public class moveNSDeclaration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, VTDException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        String xml="<document-element xmlns=\"uri:ns1\">\n"+
                "<foo>\n"+
                "<bar xmlns=\"uri:ns2\" xmlns:ns3=\"uri:ns3\">\n"+
                "<ns3:foobar/>\n"+
                "<ns1:sigh xmlns:ns1=\"uri:ns1\"/>\n"+
                "</bar>\n"+
                "</foo>\n"+
                "</document-element>\n";
        vg.setDoc(xml.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false); // namespace unaware to all name space nodes addressable using xpath @*
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        FastIntBuffer fib = new FastIntBuffer();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // get the index value of xmlns declaration of root element
        AutoPilot ap =new AutoPilot (vn);
        ap.selectXPath("//@*");
        int i=0;
        //remove all ns node under root element
        //save those nodes to be re-inserted into the root element up on verification of uniqueness

        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            if (vn.getTokenType(i)==VTDNav.TOKEN_ATTR_NS){
                xm.remove(); //remove all ns node
                fib.append(i);
            }
        }

        //remove redundant ns nodes
        for (int j=0;j<fib.size();j++){
            if (fib.intAt(j)!=-1){
                for (i=j+1;i<fib.size();i++){
                    if (fib.intAt(i)!=-1)
                    if (vn.compareTokens(fib.intAt(j), vn, fib.intAt(i))==0){
                        fib.modifyEntry(i, -1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // compose a string to insert back into the root element containing all subordinate ns nodes

        for (int j=0;j<fib.size();j++){
            if (fib.intAt(j)!=-1){
                int os = vn.getTokenOffset(fib.intAt(j));
                int len = vn.getTokenOffset(fib.intAt(j)+1)+vn.getTokenLength(fib.intAt(j)+1)+1-os;
                //System.out.println(" os  len "+ os + " "+len);
                //System.out.println(vn.toString(os,len));
                baos.write(" ".getBytes());
                baos.write(vn.getXML().getBytes(),os,len);
            }
        }
        byte[] attrBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        vn.toElement(VTDNav.ROOT);
        xm.insertAttribute(attrBytes);
        //System.out.println(baos.toString());
        baos.reset();
        xm.output(baos);
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
    }
}
```

Output looks like

```
<document-element xmlns="uri:ns2" xmlns:ns3="uri:ns3" xmlns:ns1="uri:ns1" >
<foo>
<bar  >
<ns3:foobar/>
<ns1:sigh />
</bar>
</foo>
</document-element>
```